# Handling with Critical Sections in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, critical-section, qmutex

I've searched a lot for an answer to this question, but it seems there isn't any.

I'm using Qt 5.2.0 to make a TCP client with winsocks2. The language in use is C++. To make the connection loop (where I call send() and write()) I'm using QThread (that can be read here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html), it's worked well so far, but I want to be sure that there is no context switching when my program is writing or reading something. So I've thought that critical sections would be the right way to do it, but in my searches on the Internet I haven't found any way to do it and even in the Qt official documentation there is no reference to critical section.

Then here is my question: Is there some way to use critical sections in Qt? Do I need put a mutex in the section I want avoid context switching and put mutexes in other places? If affirmative, in which  parts should I put these mutexes?

I'm sorry for my English. Thanks in advance.

If there is something more that I can inform, please tell me.

Murilo G. K.

Comment: Why are you using winapi if using Qt? Use QTcpConnection, Qt has no CS, only a mutex (QMutex)

Comment: The problem is that I need to use winsocks. This is a college project and its itention is to learn about some APIs and forms programming. So, according to your answer there is no way to do it unless I use QTcpConnection, right?

Comment: You are are mixing winapi and Qt, so either fully use Qt with QTcpConnection/QMutex, or use winapi with send() recv() and EnterCriticalSection()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then here is my question: Is there some way to use critical sections
>   in Qt? Do I need put a mutex in the section I want **avoid context
>   switching**

What you seem to be indicating is kernel level critical sections, not application critical sections which only deal with concurrent execution. Kernel level critical sections are in kernel mode *only* and have nothing to do with user applications. Context switching is a kernel level idea, not user mode.

If you are asking about processor affinity, you have to use OS specific commands to set that. Qt does not abstract processor affinity.. This is the only way to be certain that your process will not jump between cores when it is scheduled.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

NOTE: There are very few situations where these functions are actually useful. Modern schedulers already want to reschedule a given thread on the same core it was running before to minimize cache misses.

If you are asking about concurrent access to same data structures by multiple threads, then QMutex and similar are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In Qt, there's no way to implement a Critical Section without context switching.

If you want to implement a Critical Section in Qt, just use [QReadLocker](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qreadlocker.html) and [QWriteLocker](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwritelocker.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Then here is my question: Is there some way to use critical sections in Qt?

The Qt alternative would be `QMutex`. Note that it is sadly much slower than Windows' critical section. That is one major grim why certain clients drop using Qt in projects in my experience. This is one part of Qt where it becomes significantly slower than the alternative solutions.

> Do I need put a mutex in the section I want avoid context switching and put mutexes in other places?

That would be the most Qt'ish way, however Qt'ish does not necessarily mean the best even in Qt software. You need to judge case by case depending on your exact scenario. You need to ask yourself how important efficiency is for you in this environment and also, whether you wish to support multiple platforms in the (near?) future.

> If affirmative, in which parts should I put these mutexes?

This is a generic thread programming question. Use the threading primitives when they need to synchronize shared resources. Here you can read a bit more about Qt threading in general.

[Thread Support in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads.html)

I am currently uncertain whether you would use anything else from Qt in your software, but if yes, I would suggest to drop the idea native Windows API usage for starter to get things done. You can always fall back to it later if the Qt usage becomes a bottleneck in your project.